# How to properly initialize/access an array of structs with multiple sources?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm working on a school assignment that requires different sources and headers.
I have my `data.h` which holds the struct information below.

```
typedef struct volunteer{
    int hours;
    int tasksCompleted;
}volunteer;

typedef struct employee{
    float salary;
    int serviceYears;
    int level;
}employee;

typedef struct person{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char telephoneNum[20];
    union{
        employee e;
        volunteer v;
    };
}newPerson;
```

I then have a `volunteer.c` and `employee.c` which contains the functions to handle things such as printing records, searching for someone by name, etc etc.

a `mainMenu.c` that displays the menu and takes user input to add a person record.

and finally, a `mainProgram.c` which ties it all together.

I'm suppose to have an array of persons[20], and I must be able to access them (get, set, etc). **My main problem is here, I'm not sure where is the proper place to initialize the array of persons, and I'm not sure where I would create the get/set functions for the persons.**

I tried to initialize in the mainMenu.c's main function like so.

```
int main(){
    //mainMenu();
    //menu();

    newPerson person[20];

    strcpy(person[0].firstName, "George");
    strcpy(person[0].lastName, "Michaels");
    strcpy(person[0].telephoneNum, "5645651232");
    person[0].v.hours= 44;
    person[0].v.tasksComplete = ;

    printf("The name is = %s\n", person[0].firstName);
    printf("The number of tasks completed is = %d\n", person[0].v.tasksCompleted);

    //testing my addFirstName method below, 1 for person[1] since I already    did person [0]
    addFirstName(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to make sure I was able to access/read properly after adding the information to person[0], so nothing important in the main right now.

I then have an `addFirstName(int num)` function that would be called from the menu.c. (however testing it from mainProgram.c atm). I'm not sure if this would be the best way to do it, but the menu counts how many records are being added, starting from 0. so int num=0, and would be addFirstName(0);

```
void addFirstName(int num){
    char firstName[20];
    printf("\n\tEnter Volunteer's first name: ");
    scanf("%20s", firstName);
    strcpy(person[num].firstName, firstName);
}
```

However, when I try doing it this way, it says that person is undeclared, even though I initialized in the main function. This makes me think I didn't initialize the array of persons in the ideal place.

Would it be better if I were to take a struct person as the function argument?

Sorry if my question is a bit messy. Basically I would just like to know where would the most logical place/method to initialize the array of persons, and the best place/method to have my get/set methods as I would need to get/set the `person` from my other sources, (volunteer.c, employee.c, mainMenu.c)

Comment: Why don't you make addFirstName take the person array as an argument as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
void addFirstName(newPerson *const person){
    char firstName[20];
    printf("\n\tEnter Student's first name: ");
    scanf("%20s", firstName);
    strcpy(person->firstName, firstName);
}
```

in main.c

```
addFirstName(&person[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. If I wanted to add the `addFirstName` function to the header, how would I do so without getting a "`unknown typename 'newPerson`'?  --- nevermind, I included the data.h in the main.h header, hopefully that's not considered taboo

Answer (score 0):

Your function addFirstName is doing reference to an array declared in main, that's why  it says person is undeclared.

Like you said you can put the person array as the function argument and it will work

```
void addFirstName(newPerson *person, int num){
    char firstName[20];
    printf("\n\tEnter Student's first name: ");
    scanf("%20s", firstName);
    strcpy(person[num].firstName, firstName);
}
```

And about the best way to to place methods for initialize the array of persons, that's up to you, you can have your own style and choose the best that works for you, since you already have `volunteer.c` and `employee.c`, maybe the nest logical step would be `person.c`